# How to redirect to another view in bootstrap tabs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

For example: when home is clicked `@Url.Action("Information", "Admin")` has to be viewed and when menu1 is clicked `@Url.Action("Information1", "Admin1")` has to be viewed.

```
<div class="container">

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        @Url.Action("Information", "Admin")
        </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        @Url.Action("Information1", "Admin1")
       </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
        @Url.Action("Information2", "Admin2")
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
        @Url.Action("Information3", "Admin3")
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is documented quite well in the Bootstrap documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tab-content` divs are intended to be used if you have rendered the HTML for each tab already, and you simply wish to show/hide them on the page (which Bootstrap does using some JavaScript).

In your case, you actually want to show different pages, so you should add **just** the 'nav-tabs' HTML to each page, and use `@Url.Action` in the hrefs instead.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="@Url.Action("Information", "Admin")">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Information", "Admin1")">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Information", "Admin2")">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Information", "Admin3")">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
```

You will need to manually control the "active" class on the `li` on each page.

If you **do** actually want to pre-render the HTML so it all shows in one page, then rather than use Url.Action as in your question, you should be rendering a set of partial views using `Html.RenderPartial` instead.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Next page is not displayed when  data-toggle="tab" is used.@Peter Bailey

Comment: Apologies, should have removed that from my example, should work without as this will remove any JavaScript binding. Have edited my answer.